# Command prompt isn't integrating anything

Tags: cmd, cygwin, integration

I installed amazonCLI, as well as Cygwin, and changed the Path env variable to:

> %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Prio;C:\Program
>   Files\Diskeeper Corporation\ExpressCache\;C:\Program
>   Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\;C:\cygwin64\bin

When I open the command prompt, first of all it is directly pointing to

> C:\Users\Stephane

(which I think is weird). And then when I input something like 'ls', the return error is:
'ls' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Can you please help me know what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: You have zapped all those other paths in that variable. You need to rebuild it.

Comment: you mean clean the Path env variable?

Comment: Run cmd. Type in `set PATH` should be a least 6 lines long in the window. You have zapped the lot and there for the "shell" cannot find anything.

Comment: I have deleted everything in PATH but c:\windows\system32 and cygwin. when I do set PATH is see these two paths, and some PATHEXT=. I'm typing ls, still not working... :(

Comment: You need to recover the stuff you deleted

Comment: I appreciate your help but I'm sorry I'm a little bit lost here. Do you have a link that details the steps? What stuff did I delete? In path?

Comment: That doesn't make a sense at all. Cygwin's commands are in directory `C:\cygwin64\bin`, so there is no reason to add another directories to your path. See my answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message you got, it's evident, that you are trying to execute *Cygwin's* commands from the **Windows Console**. That's also the reason, why it's executed in your Windows' profile directory instead of the *Cygwin's* one.

You should read the basics about using the *Cygwin* first, because it seems you don't know what *Cygwin* exactly is and how to use it. Maybe you don't need the *Cygwin* at all, it depends on what you need to accomplish. The is for example [GnuWin tool set](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net) or [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/), which are just a sets of standalone GNU tools compiled for *Windows*. *Cygwin* is more like system than standalone utilities. You can for example execute shell scripts under the *Cygwin*.

So it depends on your needs. But I simply can't imagine using *Windows* without *Cygwin* yet.

You can execute *Cygwin's* shell from the *Windows Console*, but I advice you to use **MinTTY** (which is in directory `$CYGWIN_DIR/bin`). *MinTTY* is a terminal emulator, which executes your *Cygwin* shell (*bash* by default).

To execute for example **bash** directly from the *Windows Console*, just execute `$CYGWIN_DIR/bash.exe --login -i`.

Comment: a bad installation from cygwin ftp make that I didn't have ls.exe but I had bash.exe. Include to Windows Console actually worked for bash.exe, but not for ls.exe, driving me crazy. Cleaning up and reinstalling solve my issue. Thanks for the useful read, I badly needed Cygwin to connect to my EC2 instance!

Comment: I see. Maybe *ls* is not in default packages. Still I think, that it's better to use Cygwin's commands inside some Cygwin's shell and not directly under Windows Console.